# How will DB2 handle a temp table created in a dynamically called module?

Tags: sql, db2, temp-tables, cobol

I have come to the edge of my DB2 knowledge and can't seem to find the answer to my question.

I'm writing a general module for handling authorisation. It is called dynamically from other services and returns a temp table with accounts the user is authorised to read, along with some additional information.

Now I'm wondering how the main programs will handle the temp table?
I've declared my temp table the following way (**does actually contain more columns**):

```
EXEC SQL
   DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE  SESSION.PEG_AUTH
   ( 
     Account_ID      CHAR(10)
   )
END-EXEC
```

A main program doesn't have any information about the declaration of the temp table, so would it matter if I e.g. put an index on the table?
Personally can't see how that would work, considering that the main module is compiled without knowledge of the dynamically called module.

Or is it that the main programs SQL is executed dynamically as well?

The reason for this solution is that each program calling this module will need to access a database and SELECT/FETCH information from a database.

Any help clarifying how DB2 handles this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For Db2-LUW, References to session tables (DGTT) are dynamically compiled regardless of where they appear.

Your main program (in COBOL) needs to use the same database-connection as used by the module that creates the DGTT , otherwise the main program won't be able to see the session table. So you cannot then use connection pooling.

The module can index the DGTT as and when it sees fit, without the knowledge of the main program.

Your question shows a single-column DGTT, so it invites the question why a simple result-set would not suffice, unless the main-program needs to query the session table with SQL or additional columns are possible etc.

Comment: Hi, 
I've tested that a main program can access the table so that part is cleared. 
The table does contain multiple columns
The main programs are going to SELECT/FETCH data for the accounts in the temp table from a database, so I see it being simpler to just "hand over" a table with the needed data.
Hope that help clarify..